# The current path, {% url 'post_new' %), didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get an app running in django but I encounter this error: The current path, didn't match any of these, even though I could not figure which part of the code is problematic. Here is my code: views.py: from django.shortcuts import render from django.http
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKhGg.png
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required #function based
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin #Class based
from blog.models import Post,Comment
from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,DetailView,
                                  CreateView,UpdateView,DeleteView)

# Create your views here.
class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
        # "__lte" means less than or equal to and "-" means order_by descending order

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class UpdatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_list.html'
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')

@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_pk)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
model.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comments=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('blog.post',related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
urls.py 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
    path('accounts/login/',views.LoginView.as_view(),name = 'login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
urls.py myapp
from django.urls import path
from blog import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name = 'post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name = 'post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name = 'post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.UpdatePostView.as_view(), name = 'post_edit'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/remove/', views.DeletePostView.as_view(), name = 'post_remove'),
    path('draft/', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name = 'post_draft_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment', views.add_comment_to_post, name = 'add_comment_to_post'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve', views.comment_approve, name = 'comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove', views.comment_remove, name = 'comment_remove'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/publish', views.post_publish, name = 'post_publish'),
    path('about/', views.AboutView.as_view(), name = 'about'),
]
```

Comment: Please post your html templates. Looks lije there is a typo with the brackets at the url tag

Comment: why its `)` and not `}` at last... `{% url 'post_new' %)` it should be `{% url 'post_new' %}`...??